# How can I fix image size?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, image-upload

I am using magento-1.9.2 version, now I posted different size images (400 x 400)and (750 x 750) like that. How can I show these images in same size in frontend?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to show fixed height to both these images. If that is the case try this piece of code, for `400 height`:-

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(null,400)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //Product ID
        echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($products);
        echo $products->getImage();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $products->getSmallImage();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $products->getThumbnail();
        echo "<br>";
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($products, 'small_image')->resize(163,100); // resize function is used to resize image
        echo "<br>";
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($products, 'image')->resize(400,400);
    ?>
```